# Unexpected speckling and herringbone pattern after staining

Tags: staining, door

I'm refinishing my door (without removing hardware). After staining I ended up with (both shown in the picture)

- some bright speckles in some parts of the wood (especially around the hardware) and
- a herringbone pattern in other parts of the wood

My guess is that the herringbone pattern comes from the door being warped, because it follows prominent lines in the grain. I'm not sure where the speckles are from. Before staining, I stripped the old door, used milk paint orange peel solvent to clean the stripping agent, sanded to bare wood with an orbital sander, went over with a finishing sander, and wiped with a wet cloth. (Did the solvent need longer to dry? Did I need to let it dry more from my final wipe down? Was it from shaking the can instead of stirring?).

Any thoughts on what could be causing these two issues?

[image: door after first coat of stain]

Comment: Looks like it wasn't sanded sufficiently or consistently across the whole surface. Did you progress through a series of finer grits?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. With this sort of query it is always useful to list the exact product used, in case it might have a bearing on what occurred. And for example, how can we tell if needed to let it sit for longer without knowing what you used? *"Was it from shaking the can instead of stirring?"* Hard to say for sure (again sorry, partly because we don't know what you used). But as a rule any finish you wipe on and/or wipe off bubbles become a non-issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the word stain has become debased in recent years and now covers a range of products, from pure colouring agents (which is what "stain" is supposed to refer to) all the way to finishes in their own right. If what you used was real stain you shouldn't expect it to look good at this stage because you're at the halfway mark — only after topcoat/final finish is applied do you get the completed appearance (like the areas of remaining finish between lock plate and latch).

Comment: The time you save by not removing the hardware will be tiny compared to the work you'll need to do if you ever decide to change the hardware. Also, you'll just get a better product by removing the hardware.